# How to ignore URL param with "&var="

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have in controller as optional param:

```
GetPostalCodeLocation(string postalCode, string postalCodeExt, string place = "", string district = "")
```

if in URL i dont put the var district it works, but in application is generate this url:

**Url:"http://localhost:62814/Api/Address/PostalCodeLocation?postalCode=2415&postalCodeExt=021&place=&district=Leiria"**

I cannot control the URL (is defined by platform)

Is possible in Routing set **&place=** to ignore?
Thanks

**UPDATE**
I Have this action filter

```
Dictionary<string, string> logParameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            logParameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            actionContext.Request.Properties.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, object>("watch", watch));
            actionContext.Request.Properties.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, object>("action", actionName));

            //// Create integer parameter.
            foreach (var param in actionContext.ActionArguments)
            {
                if (param.Value == null)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Parameter " + param.Key + " cannot be null");
                }
                {
                    logParameters.Add(param.Key, param.Value.ToString());
                }
            }
            actionContext.Request.Properties.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, object>("logParameters", logParameters));
            base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem. The parameters come in a field you don't care about and ignore. And you *want* to ignore them. So what is the problem? Do you get any errors, does anything not work as expected?